# Conditionally add a column based on schema version

Tags: mysql, database, migration

How do you conditionally add a column to a MySQL table if the database schema version is below a certain value? The question assumes I knew enough to create a `_Schema` table, but don't know enough to actually make use of it.

My invalid, starting-point code looks like this:

```
SELECT @version = `Version` FROM `_Schema`;
IF version <= 2 THEN
  ALTER TABLE `TheTable` ADD `TheNewColumn` smallint(5) unsigned not null;
END IF;
```

Comment: while you could do this with a stored procedure, this is typically something people just write a script to do.

Comment: What we do is write the version number in a config table, check it during startup, and alter the tables accordingly and finally update the config table with new version number. While the checking and altering and updating part takes in separate queries, I am unsure how to do it in one query.

Comment: Currently, I provide an `UpgradeDatabase.sql` file that end users run from phpMyAdmin's **Import** tab. This way the PHP application code doesn't need Admin privilege. I'm looking for the code to go in the SQL file (not necessarily a single query) or some better approach that still maintains least privilege.